# How to Handle Out of memory?

Tags: memory

We are developing a mobile app where consumers (companies) create AR content for their products.
The content ranges from simple pictures to gifs and embedded videos. We already released versions before but now some devices (especially older devices) crash due to out of memory errors.
It is worth noting that Videos are streamed, not downloaded. The issue here are the pictures that need to be decoded and made to be ready for the GPU.
restricting content size wouldn't really help because our client wants potentially infinite pictures/videos. Sooner or later we would run out of memory. The content may be small to download, but bigger to encode (jpg is compressed and transformed into per-Pixel data for example).

We already remove the content of previous products, so we have the content of only one product in memory.
My question is how should we handle such out of memory scenarios?

Comment: Don't rely on out of memory exceptions as part of the normal functioning of your program. You should ensure it never gets to that point.

Answer (score 3):

In most programming languages, an out-of-memory condition is reported by means of an exception that gets thrown. If this exception is not handled by the application, then the unhandled exception causes the application to crash. To avoid the crash, you need to catch the exception and handle it in a sensible way.

What a sensible way is to handle out-of-memory conditions depends to some extent on what is acceptable to your users. As you already identified the picture loading as a potential hotspot for memory problems, you could decide that if there isn't enough memory for all pictures, to load them one by one, right at the moment they need to be shown.

If even a single picture is too large, you can have a second fallback to inform the user that that picture isn't available to them on that device. That would give a degraded user-experience, but not as bad as a crash.

Comment: Are out-of-memory exceptions sensibly recoverable on modern general purpose platforms? (e.g. backend web apps, desktops/mobile apps, etc.?). By the time you've hit an OOM, you've already burned through gigs and gigs of compressed memory, paged memory, etc. Your app is on its last legs, and you're lucky the OS didn't kill it already